# High frequency AC power supply

Tags: mosfet, ac, high-frequency

I'm looking for methods to deliver a alternating current of 5 A at variable frequencies 0-20 kHz to an electromagnets to generate an alternating magnetic field.

I've been reading various post and threads about using/designing a DC MOSFET circuit to achieve this current at the required frequencies. However, I'm really not from an electrical/electronical engineering background but rather a mechanical engineering background. Thus, I wanted to reach to the collective knowledge of this community for advises on how to proceed with this design challenge.

Basically, the fixed constrain is obtaining/maintaining a 5 A peak currents and being able to control the frequencies (and hopefully reaching a 20 kHz frequency).

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange! What (peak) voltage do you need? Also, is it a one-off or mass production?

Comment: I remember seeing test equipment a few years back that generated variable frequency sine wave 3 phase output to 20 Amps, but it was in the big big bucks range I think it was listed as a VFG.

Comment: You could look into audio amplifiers. Power amplifiers that can drive 5 A into 8 ohms, which is 200 watts, are readily available. However, their lower limit is usually a few Hz, not DC but there may be some that do go down to DC.

Comment: @Gil "VFD" (variable frequency drive),  possibly probably the easiest solution to this one it depends how much voltage is needed.

Comment: are you wanbting to make a gradient driver?